# Creating a python batch Image operation using ArcCatalog

Tags: python, arcmap

I'm trying to work out how to create a batch operation tool in ArcCatalog, based on all `.img` raster files in a directory. I do not need to change the code, but I need to set the correct parameters.

[image: screenshot of input parameters]

Here's my code:

```
'''This script uses map algebra to find values in an
    elevation raster greater than a specified value.'''
import os
import arcpy 
#switches on Spatial Analyst
arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')  
#loads the spatial analyst module
from arcpy.sa import *      
#overwrites any previous files of same name 
arcpy.overwriteOutput=True  
# Specify the input folder and cut-offs
inDirectory = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
cutoffElevation = int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1))
for i in os.listdir(inDirectory):
    if os.path.splitext(i)[1] == '.img':
        inRaster  = os.path.join(inDirectory, i)
        outRaster  = os.path.join(inDirectory, os.path.splitext(i)[0] + '_above_' + str(cutoffElevation) + '.img')
        # Make a map algebra expression and save the resulting raster   
        tmpRaster = Raster(inRaster) > cutoffElevation              
        tmpRaster.save(outRaster)
# Switch off Spatial Analyst
arcpy.CheckInExtension('Spatial')
```

In the parameters I have selected:

1. Input Raster Raster Dataset - direction Input, Multivalue yes
2. Output Raster Raster Dataset - direction output
3. Cut off elevation - string, direction input

I add the images I want in the input raster, select the output raster and cut off elevation. But I get the error:

> line 13, in 
>   cutoffElevation =int(arcpy.GetparameterAsText(1)).
>   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have three input parameters shown in that dialog box screenshot, but only two are described in the script. (The output raster `outRaster` is being defined in line 15, not as an input parameter.)

The error you're getting is because the output raster (presumably a file path and file name) can't be converted to an integer.

There are two ways to solve that:

1. Change the input parameters within that tool definition, so you're only feeding in input raster (parameter 0) and cut off elevation (parameter 1).
2. Change the code so it's looking for the correct parameters that are currently defined -- input raster (parameter 0) and cut off elevation (parameter 2).

   ```
   inDirectory = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
   cutoffElevation = int(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))
   ```

Either way, you're making sure that the `GetParameterAsText` command is actually referring to the parameter you really want.